# How to fix a NaN from a forloop in JS (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, math, ecmascript-6, nan

I am building my own Mathematics class in JavaScript. I declare the default accuracy to 8. When I pass through it to the function changes the outcome in the `for`-loop to `NaN`.

```js
class Mathematics {
    constructor(angleType, accuracy) {
        this.PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
        this.at = angleType || "rad";
        this.acc = accuracy || 8;
    }

    Ang(angle, at) {
        let angdeg, angrad;
        switch (at) {
            case "deg" || "d" || "Deg":
                angdeg = angle;
                angrad = angdeg * this.PI / 180;
                break;
            case "rad" || "r" || "Rad":
                angrad = angle;
                break;
        }
        return angrad;
    }

    Sin(angle, at, acc) {
        let _at = at || this.at,
            angrad = this.Ang(angle, _at),
            ans = 1,
            _acc = acc || this.acc,
            temp = 1;
        for (let i = 2; i <= 2 * _acc; i += 2) {
            temp = temp * (-1) * angrad * angrad / (i * (i + 1));
            ans = ans + temp;
            console.log("sin " + i / 2 + ": " + ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    sin(angle, at, acc) { return this.Sin(angle, at, acc) }

    Cos(angle, at, acc) {
        let _at = at || this.at,
            angrad = this.Ang(angle, _at),
            ans = angrad,
            _acc = acc || this.acc,
            temp = 1;
        for (let i = 2; i <= 2 * _acc; i += 2) {
            temp = temp * (-1) * angrad * angrad / (i * (i - 1));
            ans = ans + temp;
            console.log("cos " + i / 2 + ": " + ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    cos(angle, at, acc) { return this.Cos(angle, at, acc) }

    Tan(angle, at, acc) { return this.Sin(angle, at, acc) / this.Cos(angle, at, acc) }

    tan(angle, at, acc) { return this.Tan(angle, at, acc) }
}
var MathClass = new Mathematics();

console.log("Class sin: " + MathClass.sin(1));
console.log("Math sin: " + Math.sin(1));
console.log("Class cos: " + MathClass.cos(1));
console.log("Math cos: " + Math.cos(1));
console.log("Class tan: " + MathClass.tan(1) + " an accuration of 8");
console.log("Class tan: " + MathClass.tan(1, "r", 9) + " an accuration of 9");
console.log("Math tan: " + Math.tan(1));
```

If you run the snippet you will see that the `for`-loop length is good but the answer turns to `NaN`.

You can edit the accuracy in the constructor to 9 and it works well until you change the last parameter: `MathClass.tan(1, "r", 5)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that this syntax doesn't work as shorthand for capturing multiple cases in JavaScript:

```
case "rad" || "r" || "Rad":
```

You need to use multiple `case` statements, like this:

```
case "rad":
case "r":
case "Rad":
```

**Edit:** or use `if`/`else` and a regular expression:

```
Ang(angle, at) {
    at = at || this.at

    if (/^r(ad)?$/i.test(at)) {
        return angle
    } else if (/^d(eg)?$/i.test(at)) {
        return angle * this.PI / 180
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid angle type: " + at)
    }
}
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
class Mathematics {
    constructor(angleType, accuracy) {
        this.PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
        this.at = angleType || "rad";
        this.acc = accuracy || 8;
    }

    Ang(angle, at) {
        let angdeg, angrad;
        switch (at) {
            case "deg":
            case "d":
            case "Deg":
                angdeg = angle;
                angrad = angdeg * this.PI / 180;
                break;
            case "rad":
            case "r":
            case "Rad":
                angrad = angle;
                break;
        }
        return angrad;
    }

    Sin(angle, at, acc) {
        let _at = at || this.at,
            angrad = this.Ang(angle, _at),
            ans = 1,
            _acc = acc || this.acc,
            temp = 1;
        for (let i = 2; i <= 2 * _acc; i += 2) {
            temp = temp * (-1) * angrad * angrad / (i * (i + 1));
            ans = ans + temp;
            console.log("sin " + i / 2 + ": " + ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    sin(angle, at, acc) { return this.Sin(angle, at, acc) }

    Cos(angle, at, acc) {
        let _at = at || this.at,
            angrad = this.Ang(angle, _at),
            ans = angrad,
            _acc = acc || this.acc,
            temp = 1;
        for (let i = 2; i <= 2 * _acc; i += 2) {
            temp = temp * (-1) * angrad * angrad / (i * (i - 1));
            ans = ans + temp;
            console.log("cos " + i / 2 + ": " + ans);
        }
        return ans;
    }

    cos(angle, at, acc) { return this.Cos(angle, at, acc) }

    Tan(angle, at, acc) { return this.Sin(angle, at, acc) / this.Cos(angle, at, acc) }

    tan(angle, at, acc) { return this.Tan(angle, at, acc) }
}
var MathClass = new Mathematics();

console.log("Class sin: " + MathClass.sin(1));
console.log("Math sin: " + Math.sin(1));
console.log("Class cos: " + MathClass.cos(1));
console.log("Math cos: " + Math.cos(1));
console.log("Class tan: " + MathClass.tan(1) + " an accuration of 8");
console.log("Class tan: " + MathClass.tan(1, "r", 9) + " an accuration of 9");
console.log("Math tan: " + Math.tan(1));
```

Comment: Even worse, `"rad" || "r" || "Rad"` is valid syntax: it equals `"rad"` because that's a truthy value.